# SQL query to get records

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I don't know how to frame this question - so putting the sql statement directly here.

```
declare @tbl table(Id varchar(4),Userid varchar(10),Name varchar(max),Course varchar(max))
insert into @tbl values
('1','UserID1','UserA','Physics'),
('2','UserID2','UserB','Chemistry'),
('3,','UserID1','UserA','Chemistry')
```

Now,

To get a list of users who have taken Chemistry, I would write

```
select * from @tbl where Course='Chemistry'
```

Similarly for Physics, I would write

```
select * from @tbl where Course='Physics'
```

The problem is when I try to write the query "get a list of students who haven't taken Physics". Without thinking much, I wrote this

```
select * from @tbl where Course!='Physics'
```

and it results in, which is wrong (it is getting details about UserA - though he has registered in Physics)

```
Id  Userid  Name    Course
2   UserID2 UserB   Chemistry
3,  UserID1 UserA   Chemistry
```

To fix this, I rewrote the query like this - but somehow I think this is not the right way.

```
select * from @tbl where Course!='Physics'
and Userid not in (select Userid from @tbl where Course='Physics')
```

Please help!

Comment: that's not a bad way to write that... you don't need the `Course!='Physics'` part but the `not in` part is a valid way of getting the info you want

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT *
       FROM @tlb U
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT  *
                                 FROM @tbl Inner
                                 WHERE Inner.UserId = U.UserId
                                 AND Course = 'Physics')
```

For a full discussion of `NOT IN` versus `EXISTS`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists).  The consensus seems to be that `NOT EXISTS` is preferable.

(I note that your table definition does not mark the columns as `NOT NULL`; if it would be appropriate to add that in your scenario, it would be a good idea.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the list of *students* who haven't taken physics, then I would suggest aggregation with the having clause:

```
select userId
from @tbl
group by userId
having sum(case when course = 'Physics' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

This has the obvious advantage of only returning the student ids, and not multiple rows for a student (when there are multiple other courses).  It is also an example of a "set-within-sets" subquery, and is more easily generalized than the `where` version.  On the downside, the use of `not exists` might be able to better take advantage of indexes.